# WebApi route identifying several controller types that match the same URL. How to solve?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have:

```cs
[RoutePrefix("api/Order")]
public class OrderController : ApiController
{
    [Route("~/api/Order/{id}")]
    [Route("~/api/ManualOrder/{id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(Guid id)
    {
        //Implementation
    }

    [Route("ExampleOtherNormalMethod")]
    [HttpGet]
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExampleOtherNormalMethod()
    {
        //Implementation
    }
}
```

And:

```cs
[RoutePrefix("api/ManualOrder")]
public class ManualOrderController : ApiController
{
    //Other methods
}
```

The strategy used by route rewriting is to get the "Get" method called either "/api/Order/1" or "/api/ManualOrder/1" both pointing to "OrderController", this works.

The problem is when I request any other method in the "ManualOrder" I think it gets lost and can not resolve and returns the exception:

> Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested URL.
>   The request has found the following matching controller types:
>   Project.ProxyAPI.Controllers.ManualOrderController
>   Projects.ProxyAPI.Controllers.OrderController

Does anyone know how to solve this without duplicating the "Get" method on both controllers?

P.s: This is a hypothetical example.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure your example is much more complex than the one you present here. But based on the information in your example you could let `ManualOrderController` inherit from `OrderController`. I think it makes more sense when you assign the routes. The `Route`-attributes will not be inherited, so it shouldn't be any problem.

> Does anyone know how to solve this without duplicating the "Get"
>   method on both controllers?

Yes, it will be a duplicate, but it won't contain any logic it will just be a fall-through...

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Order")]
public class OrderController : ApiController
{
    [Route("~/api/Order/{id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public virtual Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(Guid id)
    {
        //Implementation
    }

    [Route("ExampleOtherNormalMethod")]
    [HttpGet]
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExampleOtherNormalMethod()
    {
        //Implementation
    }
}

[RoutePrefix("api/ManualOrder")]
public class ManualOrderController : OrderController 
{
    [Route("~/api/ManualOrder/{id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public override Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(Guid id)
    {
        return base.Get(id);
    }

    //Other methods
}
```

There is a downside to this approach - `ManualOrderController` will expose methods from `OrderController` via your default routing table. Depending on what your routing table looks like `api/ManualOrder/ExampleOtherNormalMethod` *may* call `ExampleOtherNormalMethod` on `OrderController`. This may, *or may not*, be a desired behavior.